# How to get different factors from a list of prime numbers?

Tags: python, list, math, sympy

I've been trying [problem 47](https://projecteuler.net/problem=47) (of project euler), the question given below:

The first two consecutive numbers to have two distinct prime factors are:

```
14 = 2 × 7
15 = 3 × 5
```

The first three consecutive numbers to have three distinct prime factors are:

```
644 = 2² × 7 × 23
645 = 3 × 5 × 43
646 = 2 × 17 × 19.
```

Find the first four consecutive integers to have four distinct prime factors each. What is the first of these numbers?

Here is my approach:(you might need to (pip) install sympy)

```
import time
import sympy

start=time.time()
a=list(sympy.primerange(1,101))

b=[] 

for i in range(646,100000):
    c=[]
    for j in a:
        if i%j==0:
            c.append(j)
            if len(c)==4:
                s=[str(o) for o in c]
                res=int("".join(s))
                b.append(res)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

print(b[:4])
end=time.time()
print(end-start)
```

How do i implement the logic that the factors should be different?
the answer which i get now(which is obviously wrong ) is :23511
the correct answer is:134043

sympy prime numbers basic functions: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-functions-python-sympy

Thanks !

Comment: This another problem that can be done with a modified sieve. The sieve entries are initialized to zero and contain an integer which represents the number of distinct prime divisors of that number. Look for the next zero entry which will be the next prime. Set that entry to one, and then "sieve out" that prime, adding 1 to each entry hit (each multiple of the prime). Whenever you set an entry to k, search forward and backward to see how many consecutive entries are equal to k. You don't know how far to search a priori, so a segmented sieve can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets supose you have a function that gives you the prime factors

```
def find_4_diff(i):
    fact_i = find_factors(i)
    fact_i_plus_1 = find_factors(i+1)
    if all([f_i not in f_i_plus_1 for i in fact_i]):
        fact_i_plus_2 = find_factors(i+2)
        if all([f_i not in f_i_plus_2 for i in fact_i]) and  all([f_i not in f_i_plus_2 for i in fact_i_plus_1]):
            fact_i_plus_3 = find_factors(i+3)
            if all([f_i not in fact_i_plus_3 for i in fact_i]) and  all([f_i not in fact_i_plus_3 for i in fact_i_plus_1]) and all([f_i not in fact_i_plus_3 for i in fact_i_plus_2]):
                return i
    return 


i = 646
myval = find_4_diff(i)
while  myval is None:
    i += 1
    myval = find_4_diff(i)
print(i)
```

Now you can think of ways of optimizing:
e.g. you are always calculating at least the factorss of i+1 so dont need to do it again (ccan pass it as an argument), if factors i+1 are not valid vs factorsi+2 you can skip i+1 etc etc

All you need is  afunction to return factors of a number as numbers e.g. 2 to the 3 returned as 8 etc

Comment: wow thanks, one small question tho, why are there 2 return statements in def?

Comment: oh it is a way to make the function stop, if it does not go into the 'if' statement it will return (return with nothing in python means return None) you could remove it by the way, the default return is None

Answer (score 1):

Your `res` is a concatenation of factors, not the product of 4 numbers that divided `i` evenly. Instead of converting the elements of c to strings and concatenating them, try just `b.append(prod(c))` where you have import `prod` as `from sympy.core.mul import prod`. Doing this, `[2, 3, 5, 11] -> 330` instead of `23511`.

BTW, `len(sympy.factorint(n)) == 4` will tell you if `n` has 4 distinct factors.